# Xcode Instruments and persistent allocations

Tags: objective-c, allocation

Trying to get into memory management and whilst looking for leaks I encountered an issue. I have an app that places a score (int) for a level in an NSMutablearray for it to be saved, and when I "replace" it in my array (I know I probably shouldn't be doing it this way in particular but anyway) it leaves a persistent alloc. I guess my issue arises because it is a percentage, and I get the problem when doing the math. If I do something like:

```
NSNumber *test = [NSNumber numberWithInt:score];
[scores replaceObjectAtIndex:level withObject:test];
```

There is no problem. But if I do something like

```
float testing = (float)score/(5) * 100;
NSNumber *test = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:testing];
[scores replaceObjectAtIndex:level withObject:test];

or

[scores replaceObjectAtIndex:level withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score]];
```

Then I get the issue. I always get 1 CFNumber Malloc called from NSPlaceholderNumber from the allocations instrument. I init my array and then the only method is:

```
score = 75;

float testing = (float)score/(5) * 100;
NSNumber *test = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:testing];

level++;

[scores replaceObjectAtIndex:level withObject:test];
```

I don't understand why one way would cause it and not the other, or how I should do it correctly to avoid this issue? I even made another project which ONLY does this routine and I still have the issue. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: +numberWithInt increments NSNumber's retain count.  Plain and simple.

Comment: how would I decrement it in this case? I am not having an issue when using numberWithInt, however.

Comment: CodaFi's comment is wrong (actually, it doesn't make sense);  +numberWithInt: returns an autoreleased object.  When in the array, it is retained. When removed, released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define what your consider to be a problem.

Both `numberWithInt:` and `numberWithFloat:` return an object that you must retain for it to live on beyond the scope of the call to that method.   Shoving the object into the array, as you do, causes the object to be retained by the array and, thus, it'll stick around under ownership of the array.

There is no leak in that code, nor any problem **in that code**.

A key to remember is that the leaks instrument shows you *where a leak was allocated* but doesn't show you the line of code that caused the leak.   I.e. if the `test` number is being leaked, it is because it is being over-retained somewhere else.

---

Wait -- what do you mean by "persistent allocation"?  I.e. the int sticks around? Note that for certain values of integers, NSNumber has singletons.

Comment: I stripped down my code while trying to understand what may be happening so this is really the only method I am calling. I updated my original post. Just having a hard time understanding why it is not an issue if I leave it as an int (but since I'm trying to utilize a percentage, that isn't useful to me). Still learning :/

Comment: I apologize for my convoluted post, it was late and myself makes little sense since I left out info. I was running the Allocations tool and I was referring to the #persistent in the heapshots analysis. I assumed it was the object that was causing the issue but playing around with it more leads me to the "level" int that I am replacing the index for. When create and increment it locally, I don't get the issue. If I use my variable that other methods access (like above), then I get the issue. I realize that 1 count and 16bytes is negligible; just trying to understand the process.

Comment: Nevermind me. So what you're I am seeing is the object being held by the array, right? I feel dumb now.